# Truncate & Expand the string in Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

On my Ruby On Rails application i have the situation like when I show the string value it should display only 100 characters when users mouse over the string value it should show all the string values .

For example : An example is al..

On mouse over : An example is always better than description situation.

i tried with Ruby On Rails build-in func => truncate(title.to_s,:length=>100). i know i can only truncate by using the above.

What is the solution for the above either Ruby On Rails solution or jQquery solution  is  best

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expand the text on a mouseover, then I'd suggest implementing the solution in jQuery as it means that the full text will be visible to those who don't have JS on (i.e. It's good for accessibility). The following is based on something we use on our website, and the full/shorted text is toggled by clicking on the text rather than hovering on it, but changing to a hover event should be fairly simple.

Firstly wrap the text you want to auto expand/contract in a div/span with a class you can use to pick it up in jQuery later.

```
<div class="autoShorten">An example is always better than description situation.</div>
```

Then create the following jQuery function:

```
jQuery.fn.autoShorten = function() {
return this.each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 100) {
        var words = $(this).text().substring(0,100).split(" ");
        var shortText = words.slice(0, words.length - 1).join(" ") + "...";
        $(this).data('replacementText', $(this).text())
        .text(shortText)
        .css({ cursor: 'pointer' })
        .hover(function() { $(this).css({ textDecoration: 'underline' }); }, function() { $(this).css({ textDecoration: 'none' }); })
        .click(function() { var tempText = $(this).text(); $(this).text($(this).data('replacementText')); $(this).data('replacementText', tempText); });
    }
});
};
```

This function also has the benefit of inserting the ellipsis on a word break rather than in the middle of the word

finally in your `$(document).ready` function add
`$('.autoShorten').autoShorten();`

Answer (score 0):

This can work nicely.

```
$(".inner").mouseover(function(){
  $(".inner").animate({"marginLeft": "-=100px"}, "slow");
});

$(".inner").mouseout(function(){
  $(".inner").animate({"marginLeft": "+=100px"}, "slow");
});
```

See it at work here:   **http://jsfiddle.net/R4Xyd/5/**